# Source a variable from a txt file?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have this code where a variable gets stored a list of server names to create snapshots in vmware vcenter but I don't want to type the server names in the script, I want the variable to be sourced by an external txt file instead, how can I achieve that?

This is what I actually have:

```
$VMList = @("Pepermint-1", "Pepermint-2")

Function CreateSnapshot {
    Foreach ($VM in $VMList) {
    Write-Host "Creating Snapshot for $VM"
    New-Snapshot -VM $VM -Memory -quiesce -Name $SnapShotNameComplete -RunAsync
                             }                           
                                    }
```

I need the variable $VMList to get/read/import the server names list from an external txt file like:

Pepermint-1,Pepermint-2,Pepermint-3

Comment: `Get-Content` reads text files, and `-split` splits strings into an array of tokens by a given separator. Thus, a single-line file with comma-separated names can be read as follows: `$VMList = (Get-Content servers.txt) -split ',')`

Answer (score 0):

Well this did it for me:

```
$VMlist=get-content c:\Users\administrator\documents\vmlist.txt
```

list items in the txt are in a new line each.

Comment: You've changed the premise of your own question with this answer, which isn't helpful to future readers - please only post answers that address the question _as asked_.

Answer (score -1):

These are simply Comma Separated Values the basic loop is as follows:

> pepper.csv
>   Pepermint-1,Pepermint-2,Pepermint-3

```
$path = "c:\foo\pepper.csv"
Import-csv -path $path | 
foreach-object `
{ 
  // Your code for each value in here. 
}
```

However a cursory google search reveals [functionally infinite tutorials on this](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&ei=2cRcXYCPNp_A3LUPiO-QmAI&q=powershell%20import%20comma%20seperated%20values%20from%20text%20file&oq=powershell%20import%20comma%20seperated%20values%20from%20text%20file&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i10.5485.9959..10053...4.2..0.279.3642.0j14j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.nxbd8RFXANg&ved=0ahUKEwjA39bVjJPkAhUfILcAHYg3BCMQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)

Comment: I have removed the commas in the txt file and left spaces between the names like: Pepermint-1 Pepermint-2 Pepermint-3
Now I'm trying something like this: 

$VMList = @(Get-Content foreach-object { """ + $_ + "","} -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\vmlist.txt")

But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `$temp = cat file.txt; $servers = $temp.split(' ')`

Comment: `Import-Csv` wouldn't work on a file that doesn't have _column headers_. To process the file as a  CSV, you would have to supply headers with `-Header`, which, however, requires you to know the number of columns (server names) in advance, and would make subsequent processing of the _one and only_ resulting  object cumbersome. In short: `Import-Csv` is the wrong tool for the job.